# How to group and join to get counts?

Tags: c#, linq

How can I join two tables to get the following results in the pictures below?  I want to get the counts of the project names.

I know I can group by Project ID:

```
var TotalSupportsByProject =
    from s in db.MySupportContext
                .GroupBy(s => s.ProjectID)
                .Select(g => new { ProjectId = g.Key, Total = g.Count() })
    select s;
```

[image]

Comment: any effort from your side?

Comment: I think it's Group & Count? What's wrong with that long inline code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join and group.  It appears you are trying to get the counts of support for each of the projects.

```
var query =
    from s in db.Support
    join p in db.Project on s.ProjectId equals p.ProjectId
    group 1 by p.ProjectName into g
    select new
    {
        ProjectName = g.Key,
        TotalSupport = g.Count(),
    };
```

If you need to be able to include counts of projects with no support, some adjustments would have to be made.  Assuming the `Project` table contains a all of the projects you need:

```
var query =
    from p in db.Project
    select new
    {
        p.ProjectName,
        TotalSupport = db.Support.Count(s => s.ProjectId == p.ProjectId),
    };
```

Comment: Thanks this what I wanted.

Comment: Is it a requirement to return projects without Support records?

Comment: @JeroenHeier: Good call, that might be useful to have just in case.